# Issues with form_for following ruby tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax-error, form-for

Good afternoon,

I'm starting out with rails and as I'm following the guide at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html I seem to have hit a roadblock.

When I try to use the form_for helper passing an array as a parameter (as explained in section 6.4 of the guide) I get the following error

> Showing [MyPath]/app/views/posts/show.html.erb where line #11 raised:
>
> [MyPath]/app/models/comment.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, ?  expecting $end

The code of the view that is being rendered is

```
<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @post.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Text:</strong>
  <%= @post.text %>
</p>

<%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :commenter %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :commenter %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :body %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>
| <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post) %>
```

This is what the post model looks like

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  validates :title, presence: true,
            length: { minimum: 5 }

end
```

and this is what the comment model looks like

```
Class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

What could be causing this issue? The "End" tags seem to match up properly.

Just for extra info, in case it is necessary

**ruby -v**

ruby 1.9.3p429 (2013-05-15 revision 40747) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]

**rails -v**

Rails 4.0.0

Thanks for any help. I'm not sure if more information is needed but please feel free to let me know.

Comment: I just realized that the issue was that the comment model was declared as Class rather than class. This is what was causing the issue.

Comment: Yes,I also found that and put it in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the typo is here -

`Class Comment <` It should be `class Comment <`